How do I Scrape Data to File from Website
I am trying to download the Passenger data from this website and save it to a csv file on my hard drive: https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx?Data=1
The code below will do most of that. I am specifically trying to change the table on the web page to filter the data where Denver International Airport is the Destination airport using the picklist Select an Airport and also setting it as the Destination using the link below the picklist. The Carrier picklist can be set to the default of All U.S. and Foreign Carriers. Can't seem to figure out the correct parameters to pass to filter the table to DEN as the destination airport for all carriers. Any help would be appreciated. New to python, so patience is also appreciated.
This is the code I am using. As I said, it does create a csv file on my hard drive, but it isn't filtered for just Denver International Airport Passengers.
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

# Set up the URL and parameters
url = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx"
params = {
    "Data": "1",
    "Carrier": "All",
    "CarrierList": "All",
    "AirportList": "DEN",  # This ensures we're filtering for Denver
    "Submit": "Submit"
}

# Make the request
response = requests.post(url, data=params)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request successful. Proceeding to parse the data.")
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")

# Parse the HTML content
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)

# Find the correct table  
df = dfs[-1]

# Display the first few rows and info about the dataframe
print(df.head())
print(df.info())

# Define the file path
file_path = r'C:\Users\harddrive\passenger_data_DEN.csv'

# Save the dataframe to a CSV file
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

print('Data saved to ' + file_path)


first use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox (tab Network) to see what browser sends to server.

this page sends also values like __VIEWSTATE and maybe it is important for server.

page also uses some cookies and maybe it is important for server.

when I open page in browser then Data=1 is in URL, not in POST data - maybe it is also important. it would need to use post(..., params={"Data": 1}, data=params) and remove this value from data=

If you use DevTools (tab Network) in Chrome/Firefox then you can see that POST sends also values __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT, __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION which can be very important to correctly generate output.
It also sends some Cookies which probably server may compare with values __VIEWSTATE,etc. - so it may need to use Session()
So first you can GET page, to get cookies in Session(), and to search values in <input type="hidden"> and add them to data which you POST to server.
Full working code:
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx"

# values send as `form`
data = {
    #"Carrier": "All",
    "CarrierList": "All",
    "AirportList": "DEN",  # This ensures we're filtering for Denver
    #"AirportList": "BOS", # Test other filter
    "Submit": "Submit"
}

# values send in url
params = {
    "Data": "1",   # send in url, not in form
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
}

session = requests.Session()  # session to keep cookies

# --- GET ---

print('GET:', url)
response = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
all_items = soup.find_all('input', {'type': 'hidden'})    

print('len(all_items):', len(all_items))
for item in all_items:
    name = item['name']
    value = item['value']
    print('name:', name)
    print('value:', value[:100])  # don't display all 
    print('-----')
    data[name] = value  # add values to dictionary
    
# --- POST ---         

print('POST:', url)
response = session.post(url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request successful. Proceeding to parse the data.")
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")

# Parse the HTML content
dfs = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(response.text))

# Find the correct table  
df = dfs[-1]

# Display the first few rows and info about the dataframe
print(df.head())
print(df.info())

# Define the file path
#file_path = r'C:\Users\harddrive\passenger_data_DEN.csv'
file_path = r'passenger_data_DEN.csv'

# Save the dataframe to a CSV file
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

print('Data saved to:', file_path)


Variable __VIEWSTATE means that server uses Microsoft® ASP.NET to generate page.
In code I see some <script> near <input type="hidden"> so maybe it uses it to calculate some extra values (for security) but code worked for me without JavaScript. But if it would use JavaScript to calculate values then it would need to use Selenium (instead of requests) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Thank you! That worked! I appreciate your help!

if it helped then you can mark answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote it.

don't forget to close() the session at the end, notice that it supports also a context manager form
